# How to send a file response to a user in Django application after some processing

Tags: python, django, fileresponse

I'm working on a solution which translates CSV/TSV files from one language to the other. I've built a Django application that accepts the file and the target/source language(s) using a form.

Once the user provides the data, the file is processed (which takes some time). Now I know we can return a fileresponse to the user. However, as I mentioned it takes time for the file to be translated and a new file is created which would contain the translated contents.

And in the meantime, I don't want to make the user waiting on the form...waiting for the response.

The models.py file is:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

file_type_choices = [
    ('CSV', 'Comma-Separated Values'),
    ('TSV', 'Tab-Separated Values')
]
valid_extensions = ['tsv', 'csv']
# Create your models here.
class FileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files", \
                            validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=valid_extensions)])
    file_type = models.CharField("Choose your file type", choices=file_type_choices,max_length=3)
    source_language = models.CharField("Choose the language in which file is", max_length=30)
    target_language = models.CharField("Choose the language to which you want to translate the file", max_length=30)
```

the forms.py file:

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

file_type_choices = [
    ('CSV', 'Comma-Separated Values'),
    ('TSV', 'Tab-Separated Values')
]

valid_extensions = ['tsv', 'csv']

class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(allow_empty_file=False, \
                           validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=valid_extensions)])
    file_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=file_type_choices, widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
    source_language = forms.CharField(max_length=30,\
                                      widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "placeholder": "English"}))
    target_language = forms.CharField(max_length=30, \
                                      widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
```

the views.py contains the following code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, request
from .forms import FileUploadForm
from .models import FileModel
from django.views import View
from csv_trans import translate

class CreateProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = FileUploadForm()
        return render(request, "translate/index.html", {"form": form})
    
    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            file_instance = FileModel( file = request.FILES['file'], \
                             file_type = request.POST['file_type'], \
                             source_language = request.POST['source_language'], \
                             target_language = request.POST['target_language'])
            file_instance.save()
            
            separator = "," if file_instance.file_type == "CSV" else "\t"
            """ if file_instance.file_type == 'CSV':
                separator = ','
            else:
                separator = '\t' 
            """
            print(separator)
            translate(str(file_instance.file), file_instance.source_language, \
                      file_instance.target_language, separator)
            
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks")
        
        return render(request, "translate/index.html", {"form":submitted_form})
```

Now in the views.py file, I'm currently using the HTTPResponse to redirect to another URL. But here I want to send a file (*translated file*) to the user, after the file that the user entered in the form has been translated.

The **csv-trans** module contains the necessary code for translating the code.

The template **index.html** contains the following HTML code alongwith DTL:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Translate data to English</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">
          <div class="form-group">
             <form class = "form-control" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
                {% csrf_token %} 
               {{form.as_p}}
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Translate</button>
             </form>
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you two ways to serve files in Django.

First: Serving files on the fly (when they are not stored in your filestorage) but are created during runtime.

```py
from django.http import FileResponse
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        your_file = create_file_logic()
        your_file.save(buffer)


        # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
        # present the option to save the file.
        buffer.seek(0)
        return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename=f"my_filename.xyz")
```

Second: Serving files from storage

```py
from django.http import FileResponse
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return FileResponse(open(path_to_file, 'rb'), as_attachment=True, filename="my_filename")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to download the file with filename starting with dot(.) and also has multiple dots. With the above solution the downloadable file removes the first dot from the filename to be downloaded.